# Why when moving/animating the text, the text is not clear?

Tags: animation

The first image is a screen grab when the text was moving. The second one is when I paused the animation.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to say, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It seems just to be a real time render problem. Try render it and see the rendered animation.

Comment: Maybe you have motion blur enabled ?